# Difference between leftJoin and leftJoinAndSelect in TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have the following query using `TypeORM` on a `NestJS` backend with `PostgreSQL`:

```
const queryBuilder = this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .select([
        'user.id',
        'userWallets.balance',
        'userWallets.currency',
      ])
      .leftJoin('user.userWallets', 'userWallets')
```

In `user entity` the one to many relationship with UserWallet is defined.

```
 @OneToMany(() => UserWallet, (userWallet) => userWallet.user)
  userWallets: UserWallet[];
```

And the many to one with User in `user wallet entity`

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.userWallets)
  user: User;
```

There are two wallets per user, so when I write the query as above I'm getting the expected array of userWallets but it only always has one element. If I write the query with a `leftJoinAndSelect` then I get the expected two elements in the userWallets array.

```
const queryBuilder = this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .select([
        'user.id',
      ])
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.userWallets', 'userWallets')
```

I thought that by including the user wallets field in the main `select` I would get them all, but there seems to be a difference and I cannot find any clarification in the TypeORM docs or elsewhere. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add .getMany(), the different is if you need show properties from userWallets you have to use leftJoinAndSelect, but if you only need userWallets for example on a .where() but u doesn't need show properties from userWallets only use this entity on the .where() you could use leftJoin

```
const queryBuilder = this.usersRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.userWallets', 'userWallets')
      .select([
        'user.id',
      ])
      .getMany()
```

here there's an exmple

```
return await repository.createQueryBuilder('letra')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('letra.Comentarios', 'comentarios')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('letra.Configuraciones', 'configuraciones')
    .leftJoin('letra.Usuario', 'usuario')
    .leftJoin('letra.Cancion', 'cancion')
    .where('usuario.UsuarioId = :usuarioId AND cancion.CancionId = :cancionId', {
        usuarioId, 
        cancionId
    })
    .getManyAndCount()
```

I wanna show lyrics from certain user and certain song so I use leftJoin because I need in the where

```
.where('usuario.UsuarioId = :usuarioId AND cancion.CancionId = :cancionId', {
        usuarioId, 
        cancionId
    })
```

But in this example I don't wanna show the properties from user and song, what I wanna show is my lyrics and this

```
.leftJoinAndSelect('letra.Comentarios', 'comentarios')
.leftJoinAndSelect('letra.Configuraciones', 'configuraciones')
```